# How to fix input flickering issue on IE11 once we apply masking?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I am using `jquery.maskedinput.js` plugin to add phone number masking to two fields through a common class assigned to it. This works fine in other browsers except for IE11.

**Issue:** Due to masking applied, focus keeps on shifting between both these fields continuously in loop, disabling the user to enter content.

Any help to fix this would be appreciated.

```
$(".classname").mask("(99)99999999");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after couple of R&d and major hit and trial we have done this issue to set masking on focus.

```
$(".classname").focus(function(){
          $(this).mask("(99)999999999");
});
```